# Recovering app files on Heroku to their state prior to a wrong push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a hobby-dev rails app on Heroku. I dumped my database to seed.rb using "heroku run rake db:seed:dump". Then I pushed my local branch to Heroku, which replaced the seed.rb file. Then I did something terrible which deleted many things from my database.
Is there any way to recover the version of seed.rb file before I pushed my local branch? (Note that if I revert to the previous commit, the seed.rb file does not contain the dump data).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go back to the previous release using the [`heroku rollback`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback) command.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback for details.

Comment: But my seed.rb is empty in the previous release. I dumped my heroku database to seed.rb after my previous release.

Comment: Is your seed file intact in any previous release? You can list your releases with `heroku releases`, and then do `heroku rollback` specifying a release number.

Comment: No, unfortunately the seed file is not in any of the releases. That's why I just need to undo my last push without returning to the previous releases.